# With CommunityToolkit and weak references, how could I subscribe to messages from an specific object?

Tags: c#, windows-community-toolkit

I am reading some examples and the main code is this:

Sender:

```
_messenger.Send(new MessageString(Input.Text, true));
```

receipt:

```
messenger.Register<MessageString>(this, (recipient, message) =>
{
    MyhandleMethod();
});
```

And this is the class that I use as message:

```
public record MessageString(string Message);
```

If I don't understand wrong, this means that the receipt, receive all the messages which that use MessageString as parameter.

So if many objects use MessageString, it means that I would receive messages from objects that I don't want.

Is there some way to set in some way to register messages from a specfic object?

I guess that one option it is to define specific messages like MessageFromMyObject01, but this doesn't solve the problem in some cases.

I could have many instances of an object in my application, because for example it is a control that I reuse in many parts of my application, but if I have another control that shows details of an specific instance, if I receive all the messages from all instances, it wouldn't be good.

When I use events, I can subscribe to the events of an specific instance,but i don't know if this is possible of meassaging, or perhaps I am trying to use messaging for the same use case than events and they are two different things.

So in summary, I would like to know if it is possible to subscribe to the messages from an specific instance, instead of receiving the messages of all the instances that send a message with and specific message object.

Thanks.